# How To Export datagridview result to excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export

I want to export my datagridview result to excel but I got this error:

> 'DataGridViewColumn' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnName' and no accessible extension method 'ColumnName' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And

> `DataGridViewRow` does not contain a definition for 'ItemArray' and no accessible extension method 'ItemArray' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
OfficeExcel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add(Default, excelWorkBook.Sheets[excelWorkBook.Sheets.Count], 1, Default);
excelWorkSheet.Name = "ECM";//Name worksheet

//Write Column Name
for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid1.Columns.Count; i++)
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[inHeaderLength + 1, i + 1] = metroGrid1.Columns[i].ColumnName();

//Write Rows
for (int m = 0; m < metroGrid1.Rows.Count; m++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < metroGrid1.Columns.Count; n++)
    {
        inColumn = n + 1;
        inRow = inHeaderLength + 2 + m;
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[inRow, inColumn] = metroGrid1.Rows[m].ItemArray[n].ToString();
        if (m % 2 == 0)
            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + inRow.ToString(), "G" + inRow.ToString()).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FCE4D6");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Name` not `ColumnName`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.name?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `Cells` not `ItemArray`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells?view=netframework-4.8